# accessing value of a random variable in PyMC3

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

In PyMC2, there are methods random() and value() to generate a random value, and get the current value of random variables. Is there any way to do the same in PyMC3?

```
p = pm.Dirichlet('p', theta=np.array([1., 1., 1.]))
p.random()
p.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite yet, but there is an almost done PR here: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/pull/784

There is no real .value as we store state outside of the RVs now.

Comment: The reason I ask is mostly for debugging. When I define a distribution, I want to see what values it generates without running the entire simulation. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: The new random() method should give you that, no? Or do you just want to evaluate the PDF?

Comment: Yes it should, but as "twiecki" said it is not ready. I thought there might be some other ways around while we wait it to be ready.

Comment: You could plot the PDF. Something like np.exp([dist.logp(val) for val in np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)])

Comment: @twiecki, is there a way to do this (p.value) now?

Comment: No, but there is .random() now. We store state (i.e. value) outside of the model now rather than attach it to the RV. What are you trying to do?