# Is it possible to create a hierarchical model in PyMC3 using Categorical random variables?

Tags: python, bayesian, categorical-data, pymc3

I'm trying to compare two models ([example](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/08/07/frequentism-and-bayesianism-5-model-selection/) from Jake Vanderplas' blog) using PyMC3, but I can't get my modified code to work (the functions `best_theta()` and `logL()` are explained in Jake's blog post, which is available in [IPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/jakevdp.github.io/downloads/notebooks/FreqBayes5.ipynb) form):

```
degrees = [1, 2, 3]

# best_theta() finds the best set of parameters for a given model
thetas = [best_theta(d) for d in degrees]

n = len(degrees)
prob = np.array([ 1 for _ in degrees ])

# model specs
from pymc3 import Model, Dirichlet, Categorical, DensityDist

with Model() as bfactor:
    choices = Dirichlet('choices', prob, shape=prob.shape[0])

    choice = Categorical('choice', choices)

    indmodel = [0] * len(degrees)
    for i, d in enumerate(degrees):
        # logL() calculates the log-likelihood for a given model
        indmodel[i] = DensityDist('indmodel', lambda value: logL(thetas[i]))

    fullmodel = DensityDist('fullmodel', lambda value: indmodel[choice].logp(value))
```

That raises an exception, because the variable `choice` is an RV object, not an integer (unlike in PyMC2), as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485354/accessing-value-of-a-random-variable-in-pymc3). In my code, however, the value of `choice` is important to make it work.

My question is, is there a way to access the value of the RV `choice`, or more generally set up a hierarchical model using Categorical random variables (i.e. use the value of a Categorical RV to calculate the log likelihood of another RV)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a quick stab at this. However, the approach needed to be changed quite a bit as it's often more convenient to vectorize the model. This also revealed a bug which I fixed (https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/commit/c784c478aa035b5113e175145df8751b0dea0df3) so you will need to update from current master for this to work.

Here is the full NB:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1ada3388a40ae767a8d

It doesn't seem to quite work yet as the results are not identical but it's a step into the right direction.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I like your solution, the model specification is clearer than mine. As you can probably tell, I'm just starting out with PyMC3. So, as best as I can tell, you can reference RV objects as you would their current values in the current MCMC step, but only within the context of another RV. In other words, your `coeffs[choice, :(choice+1)]` snippet is legal because `coeffs` is itself a (collection of) RV, whereas my `indmodel[choice]` snippet is illegal, because `indmodel` is a regular ol' list. Is that correct?